# Use a factory in AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

When a button is clicked, I want to create a new User, and redirect the person to `http://www.myapp.com/#/user/134`.

**The below code works, but am I using AngularJS factories correctly?** It feels strange to have to define a 'createUser' function in my controller.

```
myApp.factory('User', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource("/users/:id", { id: "@id" },
    {
      'create':  { method: 'POST' },
      'index':   { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
      'show':    { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
      'update':  { method: 'PUT' },
      'destroy': { method: 'DELETE' }
    }
  );
}]);


myApp.controller('splash', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'User', function($scope, $http, $location, User){
  $scope.createUser = function(){
    User.create(
      {},
      function(response){
        $scope.user = response;
        $location.path('/users/' + $scope.user.id);
      },
      function(){
        console.log('error creating user');
      });
   }
}]);
```

Here is a view with a button for creating a new user:

```
<button ng-click="createUser()">Create User</button>
```

Comment: If you downvote, leave a comment explaining why - so the question can be improved, thanks.

Comment: Well in a project, that I'm on now, things done like you have written. I don't know about nowaday conventions, but if you don't like it( code is gonna be big in controller or something else ), you can make another service, that'll use current factory or make a directive.

Comment: look closer at examples in $resource docs

Comment: I totally follow up to @OleksandrVerhun opinion. Its JavaScript and if you coming from PHP/Python/Java/objectiveC, you will see allot of funky object interactions. Organising your codes in small controllers/factories is a good approach. The object asynchronous handling makes me feel sick some times. An almost a  good question to myself is: `Where should I stall my service layer codes`. -> `serviceName.module.js`